# how to restrict access to limited IP ranges in openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I am deploying OPENVPN community version.

After my client connects they can potentially route to services on my network, where the OPENVPN server has routes to and can access itself.

How can i tell openvpn to only be able to access a portion of my network?

For example if my openvpn can access these networks:
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/24
192.168.3.0/24

But I'd only like users on the VPN to access services on 192.168.1.0/24 only. How could I handle this?

I'm currently using UFW as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> But I'd only like users on the VPN to access services on 192.168.1.0/24 only. How could I handle this?

Set up a firewall rule that blocks access from OpenVPN clients range to anything else. Depending on your topology this firewall rule can be set on the OpenVPN machine, or another firewall in your system.

In general you should use firewalls to restrict traffic, not routes or similar.

Comment: I'm running UFW with iptables. I don't supposed you have suggestions/links on how to possibly get this done there? I'm new to vpn and a bit naive here.